# What does "p.c." next to a name stand for in academic papers?

Tags: abbreviations

What does the abbreviation "p.c." next to a name stand for in academic papers?  Here are a couple of examples:

https://www.leibniz-zas.de/fileadmin/Archiv2019/mitarbeiter/frey/frey_2004-VF.pdf#page=37

> The  following  problem  was  raised  by  H.  Haider  (p.c.).

https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:312940/FULLTEXT02.pdf#page=82

> Also,  as  pointed  out  to  me  by  Staffan  Hellberg  (p.c)  verbs
> can  be  deaccented [...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**p**ersonal **c**ommunication.

The quotes did not come from a published work, they were communicated directly to the author.

---

NOTES

*Because readers cannot retrieve the information in personal communications, personal communications are not included in the reference list; they are cited in the text only. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/personal-communications*

As suggested in the above article, the formal way of doing this is to write "personal communication"  in full, and include the date it was received.

The author has used a less formal approach by abbreviating and not giving the date. However it is clear from the context that this is the meaning because the quote says, "... as pointed out **to me** by Staffan Hellberg ..." and that is clearly a personal communication.

Comment: Interesting - can you provide any reference for your claim?

Comment: @Greybeard I've done my best - see above.

Comment: Thanks - It looks good to me.